# Insert and select from a table/array in oracle

Tags: arrays, oracle, select, insert

I have a pretty big SQL statement which returns a list of id's. I need this id-list as base for other statements. Like this:

```
open crs_result1 for ' select * from ... where id in ( select <ids> from <base_statement> ) ';
open crs_result2 for ' select * from ... where id in ( select <ids> from <base_statement> ) ';
open crs_result3 for ' select * from ... where id in ( select <ids> from <base_statement> ) ';
...
```

Of course I don't want to select the whole id-list each time for the different selects.

So, my idea was to use a table/array:

```
TYPE gt_result_rec IS RECORD
(
    id NUMBER
);
TYPE gt_result_tab IS TABLE OF gt_result_rec INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

t_results gt_result_tab;

execute immediate 'insert into t_results select <ids> from <base_statement>';
```

And than use it for all other statements:

```
open crs_result1 for ' select * from ... where id in ( select id from t_results ) ';
...
```

But this doesn't really work.

Does anyone know the problem OR has a better solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar thing can be achieved using TEMPORARY tables, like this:

```
create global temporary table temp_ids(id number) on commit preserve rows ;
```

...than insert data:

```
execute immediate 'insert into temp_ids(id) select id from <big statement>';
execute immediate 'insert into temp_ids(id) select id from <other big statement>';
execute immediate 'insert into temp_ids(id) select id from <other big statement>';
```

..finally you can use your idea:

```
open crs_result1 for ' select * from ... where id in ( select id from temp_ids ) ';
```

Using TEPORARY TABLES reach that EXECUTE IMMEDIATE will take data from the same context in which your other PL/SQL code run.

If you want to use TABLE OF RECORDS (table/array), you will need declare this ARRAY in the PACKAGE (header, not BODY!), so the field will be visible from the context of the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. ARRAY must be PUBLIC visible.